# Copying data with command button into multiple excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a command button copy data from the main sheet "all" into 4 different sheets based on wether or not they meet the requirement. i have made it work with my "Lending" with the code bellow, but in the next 3 columns i have the data "FX" "Account" and "Payments" and i would like to have this one command button work with all of the sheets. Some of the dato points will go into multiple sheets, while some would only live up to 1 of them. Anyone who knows how i can expand the code to make it work?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim AllSheet As Worksheet
Dim LendSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim RowCnt As Integer
Dim DestRow As Integer

Set AllSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("All")
Set LendSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Lending")

With AllSheet
  LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  DestRow = LendSheet.Range("A" & LendSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  For RowCnt = 2 To LastRow
    If .Cells(RowCnt, 3).Value = "X" Or .Cells(RowCnt, 3).Value = "x" Then
        LendSheet.Rows(DestRow).Value = .Rows(RowCnt).Value
        DestRow = DestRow + 1
    End If
 Next
End With
'..... Remove Duplicates
Dim LastCol As String
With LendSheet
  LastCol = Split(.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Address, "$")(1)
  .Range("A:" & LastCol).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), 
Header:=xlYes
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You will get far better help if you post what you have tried and what errors you get.

Comment: You have one loop for `Lendsheet`, just add new ones for the other sheets after

Comment: You don't need new loops - just add additional tests inside the existing loop.

Answer (score 1):

The "copy data to another sheet" can be split out into a separate sub, and that cleans up your main code, making it easier to add new checks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim AllSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim RowNum As Long

    Set AllSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("All")

    With AllSheet
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For RowNum = 2 To LastRow

            If UCase(.Cells(RowNum, 3).Value) = "X" Then
                AppendRow .Rows(RowNum), "Lending"
            End If

            If UCase(.Cells(RowNum, 4).Value) = "BLAH" Then
                AppendRow .Rows(RowNum), "FX"
                AppendRow .Rows(RowNum), "Account" '<< can copy to >1 sheet...
            End If

        Next

    End With
    '..... Remove Duplicates
End Sub

'append a range to a named sheet
Sub AppendRow(rwSrc As Range, shtName As String)
    Dim rw As Range
    Set c = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) _
                                 .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, rwSrc.Columns.Count)
    'make sure we're really copying to a blank row...
    Do While Application.CountA(rw) > 0
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    rw.Value = rwSrc.Value
End Sub
```